# ggplot2 - How to change legend when using `geom_curve()` and `scale_alpha()`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I’m trying to use `geom_curve()` and `scale_alpha()` together, but the resulting legend guide is not cool =D.
In short, I want to plot a legend for `scale_alpha()` similar to the legend of `scale_color_gradient()`.
Here is my reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

theme_set(theme_void())

data_joined <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kguidonimartins/6f49bf6ae13410799fb2eede56345fa5/raw/43486c44aee2aedf951e661ac576e46a5576a0da/country_data.csv", header = TRUE)

base_map <- borders(database = "world")
```

So, my first try was something like this. Not ideal due to the overlap. But the legend guide is ok!

```r
data_joined %>%  
  ggplot() +
  base_map +
  geom_curve(
    data = data_joined,
    aes(
      x = origin_x,
      y = origin_y,
      xend = destination_x,
      yend = destination_y,
      color = flow
    ),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")),
    size = 1.5
  )
```

[image]

So, I tried to simulate a `scale_alpha()` to maintain the legend guide.

```r
data_joined %>%  
  ggplot() +
  base_map +
  geom_curve(
    data = data_joined,
    aes(
      x = origin_x,
      y = origin_y,
      xend = destination_x,
      yend = destination_y,
      color = flow
    ),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")),
    size = 1.5,
    alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "grey95", high = "blue", n.breaks=10)
```

[image]

Not good yet, maybe using a fixed color and applying alpha (in `aes()`) as a gradient:

```r
data_joined %>%  
  ggplot() +
  base_map +
  geom_curve(
    data = data_joined,
    aes(
      x = origin_x,
      y = origin_y,
      xend = destination_x,
      yend = destination_y,
      alpha = flow
    ),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")),
    size = 1,
    color = "blue"
  ) +
  scale_alpha(n.breaks = 10)
```

[image]

I liked that solution but I was unable to change the legend guide. I want to maintain the legend guide similar when using `scale_color_gradient()`. I’m trying this from scratch changing the legend key, but the `guides()` don’t change the shape of the arrows in the legend.

```r
data_joined %>%  
  ggplot() +
  base_map +
  geom_curve(
    data = data_joined,
    aes(
      x = origin_x,
      y = origin_y,
      xend = destination_x,
      yend = destination_y,
      alpha = flow
    ),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")),
    size = 1,
    color = "blue"
  ) +
  scale_alpha(n.breaks = 10) +
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(shape = 22)))
```

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

<sup>Created on 2020-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: (1) FYI, `if (!require(...)) install.packages(...)` does *not* attach the package after installation, so your code is only reproducible on first run if all of the packages are already installed. If not, then it is *guaranteed* to fail the first time it is run, but it should run on the 2nd and subsequent attempts (assuming all packages install without error. (2) Minor, but please don't include sizable side-effect code like `install.packages(...)` in a question unless it is part of the problem. An inattentive reader trying your code might accidentally upgrade a package when not desired.

Comment: Ok, @r2evans! What do you suggest?

Comment: For (1), just `library(...)` for each package (at least in questions on SO). For the question overall, I don't know ... it's too much for me to just look at right now (and I don't have several of the packages installed).

Comment: I reduced the list of packages bringing data from another source.